# SilverStripe setting controller $url_handler through init()

Tags: php, silverstripe

Is it possible to set the (ContentController's) `$url_handlers` through the `init()` function as below?

```
public function init() {
    parent::init();

    $this::$url_handlers = array(
        '' => 'index',
        '$Project' => 'getProject'
    );
}
```

I'm asking because instead of getting the function called, I'm getting a 404, whereas when 'hardcoding' the $url_handlers in the conventional way `private static $url_handlers = ...` the code works fine and the function is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$url_handlers` property is actually a [configuration property](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/configuration/configuration/#configuration-properties) in SilverStripe terminology. This means that when you flush your cache manifest, the configuration is rebuilt and cached.

You *can* update it from `init`, but you need to do it using [the configuration API](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/configuration/configuration/), because by the time your `init` method is called the configuration manifest has already been parsed. For this reason, modifying the `self::$url_handlers` property will not have any effect.

Here's an example:

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    Config::inst()->update(
        __CLASS__,
        'url_handlers', 
        array(
            '' => 'index',
            '$Project' => 'getProject'
        )
    );
}
```

For reference, [here's the point](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.5/control/RequestHandler.php#L241-L246) where `RequestHandler::findAction` looks at the configuration manifest for the defined `$url_handlers` values.